# Question based on area and perimeter of a wall

Tags: algebra-precalculus

> A room is 16m long, 7m broad and 8m high. Find the cost of white washing the four walls of room at Rs. 7.5 per m^2, white washing is not to be done on the doors and windows, which occupies 65 m^2.

In the solution it has been given area of the four walls= 2(16+7)*8=368
What formula has been used?

Answer (score 1):

Each of the four walls is a rectangle. There are two pairs of identical rectangles (each pair consists of opposite walls facing each other). All of them have as one dimension the height ($h$) of the room, but the other dimension is either the breadth ($b$)  or the length ($l$) of the room.

Total wall area = $lh + bh + lh + bh =2h(l+b)$

Answer (score 0):

#### Add-on

Another way to visualise which sides are on the top, bottom and sides is to look at the dimensions. Since we know that the ceiling and the floor are **flat**, they have *no height*. Therefore, the remaining sides to count are the $\color{red}{16 \times 8 \ wall}$ and the $\color{red}{8 \times 16 \ wall}$; and the $\color{blue}{7 \times 8 \ wall}$ with the $\color{blue}{8 \times 7 \ wall}$.

You can then use the posts by @Deepak and @MalayTheDynamo to group, calculate and finally, find the final answer to your question.

Comment: The solution is correct. Only the walls (and neither ceiling nor floor) are being treated.

Comment: @Deepak Thanks for noticing, but I just edited the solution to reflect this.

Comment: The 16*7 shouldn't appear, and instead another 8*7 should appear.

Answer (score 0):

The area of Wall 1 is $lh$. The area of Wall 2 is $bh$. The area of Wall 3 is the same as Wall 1. The area of Wall 4 is same as Wall 2.

$\text{Total Area}\\{=lh+bh+lh+bh}\\=2lh+2bh\\=2h{(l+b)}$

---

Additional:

$\text{Area of Wall=[Total Area]-[Area Of Windows]}$

$\text{Cost=Area of Walls}\cdot\text{Rate}\\=[\{2\cdot{8}\cdot{(16+7)}\}-65]\cdot{(7.5)}\\=22725$